# what does colon mean in a merge clause in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MERGE (robert:Critic)
RETURN robert, labels(robert)
```

A new node is created because there are no nodes labeled Critic in the database.
But what is robert?and what does a colon mean?

```
MERGE (charlie { name: 'Charlie Sheen', age: 10 })
RETURN charlie
```

A new node with the name 'Charlie Sheen' will be created since not all properties matched the existing 'Charlie Sheen' node.
but in this example,there is no colon,why the variable charlie  is still returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `robert` is a variable name that has meaning only within the query in which it is used (and is not saved in the DB). It is defined and instantiated the first time it is used in the query, and as long as there is no `WITH` clause afterwards, the query will always use `robert` to refer to the  same node (or relationship, path, ...).

   A `WITH` clause will only carry forward the variables that it specifies. So, `WITH robert, foo` would allow the same `robert` variable name and value to be used after the `WITH` clause. But `WITH foo` will cause `robert` to be forgotten.
2. A colon is used in a node to designate that the following name is a [label](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels). It is also used in a relationship to designate that the following name is a [type](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-relationship-types).

Answer (score 1):

In this cypher, robert is the node while Critic is the node label

```
MERGE (robert:Critic)
```

In below, you are creating a node (without a node label) and with properties name and age

```
MERGE (charlie { name: 'Charlie Sheen', age: 10 })
```

Try below. Notice the colon BEFORE the node label

```
MERGE (:Critic)
```

In short, for your examples, colon is a way for you to differentiate if you are creating a node or a node label or both.